# An error occurred while updating the entries. see the inner exception for details for has many relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. Plans
2. PlanRoles
3. Roles

A one-to-many relationship is established for tables Plans & PlanRoles
I set the entity framework settings to "Table First".

Now when I want to create a Plan with its PlanRoles, I get this error on calling the `SaveChanges()` method.

> An error occurred while updating the entries. see the inner exception for details

This is the code I use:

```
PlanDB planDB = new PlanDB();
plan = new Plan();
plan.Name = name;
plan.Amount = amount;
plan.Status = Status;

foreach (Role item in enteredRoles)
{
    plan.PlanRoles.Add(new PlanRole() { RoleID = item.RoleID });
}

planDB.Create(plan);
planDB.Save();
```

Note: when I remove the written foreach and do not add the PlanRules to the plan object, this error does not occur but I need to add the PlanRoles as well.

PlanDB class:

```
public class PlanDB :
{
    My_ProjectEntities db = new My_ProjectEntities ();
    public bool Create(Plan record)
    {
        bool result = true;
        try
        {
            db.Plans.Add(record);
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
    public bool Edit(Plan record)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.PlanRoles.AddRange(record.PlanRoles);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Plan Model class:

```
public partial class Plan
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Plan()
    {
        this.PlanRoles = new HashSet<PlanRole>();
    }

    public int PlanID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlanRole> PlanRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Also I changed Pluralization visual setup but no diffrent

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: How I can I understand it? I checked `Exception.InnerException.Message` but it is similar to the error I mentioned in the post. I found out from Exception.InnerException.StackTrace that the error is related to SaveChanges method

Comment: So also `Exception.InnerException.Message` says to look in InnerException for details? Then look at `Exception.InnerException.InnerException`

Comment: Does the RoleId that you are setting already exist in the Roles table? If not that could be your error.

Comment: @klaus-gütter Thank you bro, with check Exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message I understand the problem is from my datetime filed formatting